# How to augment image examples when useing tensorflow queuerunner to read image data like what Cifar10 tutorials described

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, classification

In image classification problem, because the positive samples were too small.so I want to augment the image examples during the train progress, Just like the Carfi10.But it just change the examples by random crop, rotation or flip, do not increase the train examples. However, I want to augment the positive cases five times so that the total positive were six time as many as the initial numbers.How should I to do this? And I have already had an idea. Use the tensorflow control-flow 'cond' and 'while_loop' to augment the positive case five times if the label was positive. And then enqueue the augmented example to queue for the train step. How to implement this? I real need help. Many thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do this in pure tensorflow? Why not use scikit-learn's `train_test_split` to get a stratified training set and then use keras' `ImageDataGen` to do the image augmentation?

Comment: because my train data is 3D data, so I have rewrite the augment method,and I want to make full use of it. On the other hand, I want use the tensorflow framwork for deep learning and use GPU to accelerate.